# How to find specific value in Qmap

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I need to know in `QMap` second value there is. Functions like `first()` and `last()` are useless. Do i have to use iterator, some kind of loop?

```
 QMap<int, QString> map;
 map.insert(1, "Mario");
 map.insert(2, "Ples");
 map.insert(3, "student");
 map.insert(4, "grrr");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map provides quick access based upon the key (the first argument).

So, yes, if you want to know if a value exists (the second argument), you would need to iterate over the map values:-

```
bool ValueExists(const QMap<int, QString> map, const QString valExists)
{
    QList<QString> valuesList = map.values(); // get a list of all the values
    foreach(QString value, valuesList)
    {
        if(value == valExists)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

To simplify the code, we can also use the values' [contains()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#contains) method, which internally will iterate over the values, as above.

Answer (score 15):

If you find specific key or value you can do something like this:

```
// Returns 1
int key1 = map.key( "Mario" );

// returns "student"
QString value3 = map.value( 3 );
```

or do you want to iterate over all items in QMap?

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to iterate over the elements. First get all values via `values()` and then use `contains()`.

```
bool ValueExists(const QMap<int, QString> map, const QString valExists) const
{
    return map.contains(valExists);
}
```

Comment: This will allocate a temporary container for `map.values()`. Just use `map.contains(valExists);`

Comment: Regarding the edit to this question: map.values().contains(valueExists) is not the same as map.keys().contains(valueExists). The latter however is equivalent to map.contains(valExists).